# VIM Buffer/Window Hiding

Tags: vim

I'm writing a vim plugin which needs to do some special window management. What I want is as follows:

On startup, the current window will be split in two and the newly created window will be used for user input and plugin output. Let's call this the I/O window.

Occasionally the I/O window will need to be "replaced". That is, a new set of contents will replace the portion of the screen containing the I/O window. Call this the temporary window. However, the I/O window will remain saved somewhere. When the user leaves this temporary window (with :q or :q!) the contents of the I/O window will reappear in the original spot.

How would I go about doing such a thing? I've been trying things and reading about buffers and windows for a some time now in the help pages but I still can't seem to figure it out.

What I think should work is:

1. :new to split the screen on startup.
2. :set bufhidden=hide on the I/O window.
3. :enew to display the temporary window.

This works right up until the user does a :q from the temporary window. Instead of the screen remaining split, the top portion completely disappears. Attempting to quit from this point leads to errors about unsaved data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `set bufhidden=hide` with `setlocal bufhidden=hide`. It does not fix things, but this is how options must be changed by plugins in order not to touch user options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to show errors about unsaved data (and not to set modified flag), use `setlocal buftype=nowrite`. To actually save something when vim leaves or buffer is closed, try

```
new
setlocal buftype=nowrite " or even buftype=nofile, if it is possible
let s:iobufnr=bufnr('%')
augroup FooSaveIO
    autocmd!
    execute "autocmd BufUnload <buffer=".s:iobufnr."> call s:SaveIO()"
augroup END
```

where `call s:SaveIO()` must be replaced with command that saves this IO. About quiting buffer without deleting window: try [bufkill](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1147) plugin and its `:BD` command. Another way is to capture BufWipeout event for temporary window and opening third window putting IO buffer here (so that when temporary buffer and associated window are closed, IO window will be shown on their place), but there are too many ways to break this.

Comment: The buftype=nofile option is great. Thanks for that. But I still think it would be possible to have the IO window somehow be "hidden" without the use of another plugin. Is it really not possible?

Comment: @VimUser. If you don't want to use the other plugin directly, just copy code from it. And this suggestion was not about hiding IO buffer, it was about closing the buffer without closing the window. Hiding *windows* (not buffers) is not possible because window must always be shown, at least on some other tab.

Comment: Right, I meant "buffers". Anyway, it looks like BufUnload does what I want since I can just use it to open the new window again and restore the contents. Thanks!